# dimensions of Root element in reactjs not changing with children element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I was designing a navbar and faced a weird issue, which is when I am inspecting the dom in chrome developer tools, I found that children(Navbar) has a dimension but root element's dimensions still has 0 value on one axis.

image of root inspection

[image: image of root inspection]

image of NavBar inspection

[image: image of NavBar inspection]

what mistake I might be making or it is not an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `position: 'fixed'`, the element is taken out of the rendering context. So it will position itself with respect to the viewport rather than the parent.

So as far as the parent is concerned, it thinks that there is no child rendering inside of it. Hence the 0 height.

Check this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to get a better sense of the `position` property